# Trigger clipboard.js on('success') or on('error') to unit test it

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am using Jasmine Jquery for my unit testing. I have the following code:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(copyToClipboard);

  function copyToClipboard(){
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('#d_clip');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      $(e.trigger).text("Copied!");
      e.clearSelection();
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(e.trigger).text("Copy");
      }, 2500);
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
      $(e.trigger).text("Error copying");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(e.trigger).text("Copy");
      }, 2500);
    });
  }
})();
```

I already tried :

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    setFixtures("<button type='button' id='d_clip'>Copy</button>")
    clipboard = new Clipboard('#d_clip');
  });

  it('should change text to copied', function() {
    spyOn(clipboard,'on');
    $('#d_clip').trigger('click');
    expect($('#d_clip').text()).toEqual('Copied!')
  });
```

But I am getting this error:

> Expected 'Copy' to equal 'Copied!'.

It works when I manually click on. It also work when I do `$('#d_clip').trigger('click');` on Chrome Developer Console.

Looks like clipboard is not doing anything for the unit testing. I can't figure out how to do that.

**What I want to test ?**

1. I want to trigger click and make sure the text is "Copied!" when success and "Error copying" when error.

This is on Ruby on Rails, so I run JS unit tests as:

`rake jasmine:ci`

Comment: Does it work when you click on it without a test and how does it run the tests?

Comment: Yes, it works when I click on it. It even works when I do `$('#d_clip').trigger('click');` on the Chrome Developer Console. I am doing this on Ruby on Rails so I do `rake jasmine:ci`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, I would try [jasmine's `done()` callback](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). It allows your specs to be asynchronous. (Note that the spy is unnecessary for this.)

```
it("should change text to 'copied'", function(done) {
    $('#d_clip').trigger('click');
    clipboard.on('success', function() {
        expect($('#d_clip').text()).toEqual('Copied!')
        done();
    });
});
```

From a style point, however, I would recommend you split this into two smaller specs, one that tests whether the trigger was called from `copyToClipboard()`, and one that calls your callback directly (extract it is a variable) and checks whether it updates the value. Combining the two feels like an integration test to me.